# how to stack bands of satellite images located in a folder without the need to name them using gdal in OSGeo 4W Shell

Tags: gdal, osgeo

I have three satellite image bands in a folder and I want to stack them to create a colorful RGB composite using gdal in OSGeo 4W Shell, but I don't want to have to type the name of each one at the prompt, but just point it to the computer the folder where it is located

I tried in folder `C:\Users\wesley\Downloads\1\geo` but in the last phase I got an error

```
for %f in (geo\*.tif) do set files=%files% %f

gdalbuildvrt -separate virtual.vrt %files%

gdal_translate virtual.vrt mosaico.tif
```

I noticed that the end result is not a stacked RGB image, but only a grayscale image. there is some error in?:

```
for %f in (geo\*.tif) do set files=%files% %f
```